# How do I clear google chrome predictive searches?

Tags: google-chrome, android

I did some searches for [keyword] and a few other things.

Now when I type the first letter on my phone (and presumably on a computer with me signed in) into google chrome I see these predictions come up.

I really don't want people to accidentally see [keyword] therefore I want to clear this history. How can I do this?

I have tried going into privacy, checking everything and selecting since the beginning of time, but it has not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

Open Chrome. In the top right, click the Chrome menu>Click Settings > Show advanced settings. In the "Privacy" section, uncheck "Use prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar.

But it appears that completions are still there.

You will have to clear your history. Predictive word/link completions are coming from you history. I thing that there is no option to disable this feature without clearing you history. Also there is no option to manage completions as user.

Comment: I've logged into myactivity.google.com and deleted my entire search history, this has resolved the issue. I've also disabled it in there.

Answer (score 5):

chrome://omnibox/   should give you the reason for the result is included.

Comment:  Hidden gem! This is such a good answer. Never knew about `chrome://omnibox`. Trying to find more information about this tool.

Comment: This is amazing for troubleshooting! I was struggling to figure out why an address would continue to come up. Turns out it was a random bookmark buried in a folder that I wasn't aware of. All the upvotes!

Answer (score 4):

When you start typing, arrow down and highlight the desired entry. Then,     shift-delete to permanently remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the following remedy works for all machines, but it definitely works with both of my Chromebooks.

All you need to do is type your search terms in UPPER CASE letters.

Autocomplete will ignore what you're typing and will not try to complete it.

This remedy also works when you're typing a search term inside other websites such as Ebay. Simply type your search words using UPPER CASE LETTERS and Google will not try to autocomplete it.